# Assignment to readonly property error in a uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, properties, uiwebview, readonly

WHEN I WRITE:

```
self.recipeSiteView.request = recipe.page ;
```

XCODE SAY  :   "assignment to readonly property "

I modified a template code :

```
self.recipePhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.imageFile];
```

how can I use this expression for a UIWEBView?

Answer (score 0):

The `request` property of `UIWebView` is read-only. You are not allowed to set it. Hence the error. See the reference docs.

If you wish to load a new request, use the `loadRequest:` method:

```
[self.recipeSiteView loadRequest:recipe.page];
```

This assumes that your `recipe.page` property is of type `NSURLRequest`.